# Node Wrangler connects wrong inputs/output

Tags: node-editor, workflow, shortcut

I want to use lazy connect <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Drag</kbd> drag with the node wrangler but it often connects the wrong inputs and outputs. is there a way to cycle through the different inputs/outputs?

Another issue is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Z</kbd> is not working in the shader editor after a certain level of complexity. does someone have the same issue?

Comment: That's two different questions... if someone might be able to help you on the second he will not look into this, because your topic is only for the first question. It's always better to place separate questions for each topic. For the second question: what is a "certain level of complexity"? Can you be more precise? Or is it just a certain amount of steps? Under _Preferences_ > _System_ > _Memory & Limits_ you can set the number of _Undo Steps_. I think in the current version the default is 32.

Comment: For the lazy connect: if you Shift + Alt + drag, Blender shows you a list of possible inputs to choose which to connect.